# Cannot create an app that listens the webhook "pull_request_review_thread"

Tags: github-app, probot

I am trying to create a simple app that will output the payload after the webhook "pull_request_review_thread" is triggered with any action. Here is the link to the related webhook: [Pull_request_review_thread Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request_review_thread)

However, this code:

`app.on("pull_request_review_thread", async(context) =>{ app.log.info(context.payload); })`

gives the error:

`Argument of type '"pull_request_review_thread"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof EventTypesPayload | (keyof EventTypesPayload)[]'`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not having the latest version of @octokit/webhooks-types. It can be checked with the command "npm ls @octokit/webhooks-types" , current latest version is 5.8.0